# Save multiple figures in one pdf page without using subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdf, figure

I have a lot of figures and i want to get them on the same page in a pdf.
Currently i am using the PDF backend, but it only writes them on one page per figure.

What changes are needed to get a list of figures on one page?

I don't want to use subplots because of several reasons of the code. 
So let's say it is not possible to change the plotting part.
I only want to change the part where i save the figures to the pdf:

```
for i in range(number_of_figures):
    fig = figures[i]
    pp.savefig(fig)

pp.close()
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: The pdf backend produces one page per figure. So you need to use subplots to get several graphs on the same page. Alternatively you can create a pdf with one figure per page and manipulate the pdf afterwards to combine several pdf pages in one, e.g. via your printer settings.

Answer (score 0):

I have come to the same issue in the past and wasn't able to solve too.

My workaround was to save the figures to disk, then use a different module to join them.

Checkout the following code:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger

files = ['f1.pdf', 'f2.pdf']  # put the full path for the file you wanna join

merger = PdfFileMerger()
for pdf in files:
    merger.append(open(pdf, 'rb'))
joined_pdf_path = 'joined_pdf_file.pdf'
with open(joined_pdf_path, 'wb') as fout:
    merger.write(fout)
```